# Capitalize first letter in each word

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to capitalize the first letter in each word for my page title in Nuxt.js
My current code capitalizes the first word, however I need it to also capitalize the rest.

```
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.$route.params.models.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.$route.params.models.slice(1).split('-').join(' ') + ' | ' + this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
      ]
    }
  }
```

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update -

If you still need a method to do that, try this `regex` pattern

```js
function capitalize(value){
      return value.replace(/(?:^|\s|-)\S/g, x => x.toUpperCase());
}
 
 console.log(capitalize('hello i misunderstood your requirement initially by skipping the whole description'))
```

Comment: Page titles can't be changed with CSS or am I mistaken?

Comment: @MadsHjorth - Sorry I didn't read the whole description initially -

Comment: Also it will be great if you mention `page-title` in your question heading, it will be really helpful to others thanks